# Could not resolve entry module "index.html"

Tags: vue.js, vite

Использую версию vite 4.3.8
Почему при сборке проекта через команду vite build, сообщает об ошибке

```
Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
    at error (file:///D:/data/Project/detect_plate_server/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2124:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///D:/data/Project/detect_plate_server/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24011:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Структура папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    publicDir: 'public',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@themeConfig': path.resolve(__dirname, 'theme.config.js'),
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        },
    },
    server: {
        port: 9000
    },
    plugins: [
        VueI18nPlugin({
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, './locales/**')],
        }),
        vue(),
        vueJsx()
    ]
});
```